# Can not modify inside prototype array

Tags: javascript, prototype

Well the problem is with the Game's instance of rects: [], which should be array of objects Rect. When i access the rects property inside Game gives undefined.

http://jsbin.com/ibilec/34/edit

```
(function(window, document, console) {
  'use strict';

  function Rect() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 20;
    this.height = 20;
  }

  Rect.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };


  var Game = Object.create({    
    rects: [],  /// PROBLEM IS WITH this

    draw: function() {
      console.log('Draw called', this.rects);
      if (this.rects) {
        this.rects.forEach(function(rect, index) {
          console.log(rect);
          rect.draw(this.ctx);
        });
      }

      //window.setInterval(function() { this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200); }, 1000);


    },

    genRect: function() {
      var newRect = new Rect();
      newRect.x = parseInt(Math.random() * 200, 10);
      newRect.y = parseInt(Math.random() * 200, 10);

      this.rects.push(newRect);
    },

    loop: function() {
      //Game.draw();
      // Frame rate about 30 FPS

      window.setInterval(this.draw, 1000 / 30);
    },

    init: function() {
      this.canvas = document.getElementById('game'); 
      this.height = this.canvas.height;
      this.width = this.canvas.width;

      window.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');


      this.genRect();
      this.loop(); //start loop
    }
  });

  var game = Object.create(Game);
  game.init();
})(window, document, console);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `draw` method is not called as a method of the object, it's called as a function in the global scope, so `this` will be a reference to `window`, not to the Game object.

Copy `this` to a variable, and use it to call the method from a function:

```
var t = this;
window.setInterval(function() { t.draw(); }, 1000 / 30);
```

Comment: This line `rect.draw(this.ctx);` is also incorrect because the *ctx* is saved to global scope here `window.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');`

Comment: @PeterPajchl: But that code is run inside a callback function, so `this` will be the `window` object.

Comment: which callback? the one in your answer?

Comment: @PeterPajchl: No, the callback for the `forEach`.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong but based on documentation - if `thisArg` is `undefined` or `null` the `this` value depends on whether it's run in strict mode or not -> only in non-strict mode `this` value will refer to global object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @PeterPajchl: Yes, you are right, I thought that it would work as a regular callback. It will be undefined in this case, so one would need to specify `window.ctx` or send `window` as second parameter to `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you for good advise, how should the canvas context variable be global or more likely enscapsulated in object.

Comment: @jurka: If you call the `draw` method the way that I showed, you can put the canvas context in the `Game` object also, and access it using `this.ctx` in the method.